# Why isn't height behaving for an img in a bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The tomato picture is taller than the others even though I set `height` and `width`. I'm sure it's something simple:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/lightning.jpg" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail" width="230" height="230"></a>
        <div class="caption text-center">Weather App</div>
  </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/TomatoClock.jpg" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail" width="230" height="230"></a>
        <div class="caption text-center">Weather App</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/soup.jpg" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail" width="230" height="230"></a>
        <div class="caption text-center">Recipe Book</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using `.img-responsive` and `.img-thumbnail` which both set `max-width:100%` in CSS,  therefore overriding the html `width`/`height` tags

Plus don't use HTML tags for `width`/`height`

To have it with same `height` you can do something like this (without losing aspect ratio):

```css
.row img {
  max-height: 120px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/lightning.jpg" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">Weather App</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/TomatoClock.jpg" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">Weather App</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/soup.jpg" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">Recipe Book</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, and thanks for fixing my captions. I see what you mean about the aspect ratio as I added max-width to try to make them the exact same size and it readjusted so they weren't even. I ended up using just height and width in CSS vs. max-height and it seems to work as well, just stretches. If there's an advantage to max-height over height in css with bootstrap please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Set custom width and height like this in css to override bootstrap:

```
.img-thumbnail{
  width: 230px;
  height:230px;
}
```

Comment: Your code will make the columns useless because the widths are absolute.

Comment: I ended up combining that with dippas response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is bootstrap's responsive images messing with it. Override it in css like so

```
img {
  width: 230px !important;
  height: 230px !important;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Popatop15/ugcumxkt/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing from using `<img>` to using the images as backgrounds. Bootstrap is not everything, you can still add your own styles if none seems fit.

Backgrounds are good because you can trim off the ends and it won't stretch the images.

```css
.projects.img-thumbnail[style] {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#"><span style="background-image: url(http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/lightning.jpg)" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail"></span></a>
    <div class="caption text-center">Weather App</div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#"><span style="background-image: url(http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/TomatoClock.jpg)" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail"></span></a>
    <div class="caption text-center">Weather App</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#"><span style="background-image: url(http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l514/sterzarino/soup.jpg)" class="img-responsive projects img-thumbnail"></span></a>
    <div class="caption text-center">Recipe Book</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But as far as I know, there is no easy way of making it a square except involving `::before` or `::after` pseudo selectors.